# Complex array merge

Tags: php, arrays

I've been wrapping my head around this for a couple of days...

I have several arrays that need to be sort of merged into a single array. The order in which they merge is of great importance and is simply the order in which they appear in the global array (like the example below):

```
$input1 = array(
  array(
    'context' => 'aa', 'id' => 1, 'view' => 1, 'update' => 1,
  ),
  array(
    'context' => 'bb', 'id' => 2, 'view' => 0, 'update' => 0,
  )
);
$input2 = array(
  array(
    'context' => 'cc', 'id' => 3, 'view' => 0, 'update' => 1,
  ),
  array(
    'context' => 'dd', 'id' => 4, 'view' => 0, 'update' => 0,
  ),
  array(
    'context' => 'ee', 'id' => 5, 'view' => 1, 'update' => 0,
  )
);
$input3 = array(
  array(
    'context' => 'ff', 'id' => 6, 'view' => 1, 'update' => 1,
  ),
  array(
    'context' => 'gg', 'id' => 7, 'view' => 1, 'update' => 0,
  ),
);

$global = array($input1, $input2, $input3);
```

Each input array itself consists of several subarrays that are of equal structure; see http://pastebin.com/fQMUjUpB for an example. This pastebin code also includes the desired output.
The output array should contain:

- a single level array
- a tree-like passthrough upon "merging the next input array", viz. every possible cross-combination of subarrays should be made during a merge between two input arrays
- the key of each a combination should be generated as a concatenated string of the corresponding `context` and `id` elements (glued with a plus) joined together with an ampersand (&); e.g: `context1+id1&context2+id2`
- For the next merge the previous resulting array should be used in order for the example from above becomes 
  `context1+id1&context2+id2&context3+id3`
- The resulting `view`and `update` elements are calculated by simply multiplying their corresponding values during merge.

```php
$output = array(
  'aa+1&cc+3&ff+6' => array('view' => 0, 'update' => 1),
  'aa+1&cc+3&gg+7' => array('view' => 0, 'update' => 0),
  'aa+1&dd+4&ff+6' => array('view' => 0, 'update' => 0),
  'aa+1&dd+4&gg+7' => array(...),
  'aa+1&ee+5&ff+6' => array(...),
  'aa+1&ee+5&gg+7' => array(...),
  'bb+2&cc+3&ff+6' => array(...),
  'bb+2&cc+3&gg+7' => array(...),
  'bb+2&dd+4&ff+6' => array(...),
  'bb+2&dd+4&gg+7' => array(...),
  'bb+2&ee+5&ff+6' => array(...),
  'bb+2&ee+5&gg+7' => array(...)
);
```

How can this be accomplished when looping over `$global`?

I may have expressed myself quite vaguely (it's really hard to explain!), but hopefully it becomes more clear when you take a look at the pastebin code...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll never have more than 3 input arrays into the $global array?

Comment: which algorithm are you use to get that index(like 'aa+1&cc+3&ff+6') in output array  ?

Comment: @Maxime the number of input arrays in $global is varying

Comment: @fasM For every cross-combination you make, always take `context` and `id` of a subarray, combine them with a plus sign and then concatenate it with the (existing) key of the resulting output array by using an ampersand.

Comment: @fasM those values are the result of multiplication of each subarray merge. So in the case of aa cc gg, then let's say for `view` it would be `$aa['view'] * $cc['view'] * $gg['view']`

Comment: okey i understand,now can we loop from $input1$input2$input3, and not $global to generate your desired output?

Comment: Put $global in a foreach loop? I don't quite understand what you're referring to..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a minimal working code so that you can get the general idea (if you want to improve the code, feel free, there's a lot to do!):

```
function generate_output($globalArray, $context = array(), $view = 1, $update = 1, &$output = array()) {
    if(!count($globalArray)) {
        $output[implode('&', $context)] = array('view' => $view, 'update' => $update);
    }
    else {
        foreach(reset($globalArray) as $elt) {
            $newContext = $context;
            $newContext[] = $elt['context'] . '+' . $elt['id'];
            generate_output(array_slice($globalArray, 1), $newContext, $view * $elt['view'], $update * $elt['update'], $output);
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

generate_output($global);
```

Comment: Done. I made some minor changes to your answer to generalize it even more.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, using a global variable is very ugly :)

Comment: Another review is pending; instead of `$globalArray[0]` I suggested using `reset($globalArray)` to generalize the use case.

Comment: Upon taking another look at the code, what's the point of using `$newContext = array_slice($context, 0);` instead of `$newContext = $context;`?

Comment: There's no point, it's plain stupid. In PHP, arrays are assigned by copy anyway. Both expressions do the same thing, and `$newContext = $context;` is shorter and clearer. Go for it! I guess I just did a copy & paste from `array_slice($globalArray, 1)` without thinking much.